# Optimizing the design of a workflow engine database

Tags: mysql, database-design, optimization

I need help optimizing this design because I don't think it's going to scale well.

**Background info**

The database is for a *workflow engine app*. End *users* create *Transactions* with different *attributes*, and a *transaction* goes through a *series of steps* based on a *subset* of its *attributes* (right now the *subset* is 3, but it could change in the future).

The *number* and *order* of the *steps* the *Transaction* goes through comes from *routes* that I defined. These *routes* almost never change.

This is the structure of the tables that are used to find a *route*.

[image: Route Structure]

This is what the `Transaction` table looks like.

```
CREATE TABLE `Transaction` (
 `TID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Type` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `WavPost` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `EmployeeClass` char(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`TID`)
)
```

This is a view I created to generate all possible *routes* (`route_vw`)

```
  select 
    `d`.`facstaff` AS `facstaff`, 
    `f`.`waveposted` AS `waveposted`, 
    `h`.`tempreg` AS `tempreg`, 
    `j`.`step_name` AS `step_name`, 
    `i`.`route_step_id` AS `route_step_id`, 
    `i`.`route_id` AS `route_id`, 
    `i`.`step_id` AS `step_id`, 
    `i`.`ndx` AS `ndx`, 
    `i`.`on_time` AS `on_time`, 
    `i`.`behind` AS `behind`, 
    `i`.`late` AS `late` 
from 
    (
        (
            (
                (
                    (
                        (
                            (
                                (
                                    `route_defn` `a` 
                                    join `fac_staff_list` `c` on(
                                        (
                                            `a`.`fac_staff_list_id` = `c`.`fac_staff_list_id`
                                        )
                                    )
                                ) 
                                join `fac_staff` `d` on(
                                    (
                                        `c`.`fac_staff_list_id` = `d`.`fac_staff_list_id`
                                    )
                                )
                            ) 
                            join `wave_post_list` `e` on(
                                (
                                    `a`.`wave_post_list_id` = `e`.`wave_post_list_id`
                                )
                            )
                        ) 
                        join `wave_post` `f` on(
                            (
                                `e`.`wave_post_list_id` = `f`.`wave_post_list_id`
                            )
                        )
                    ) 
                    join `temp_reg_list` `g` on(
                        (
                            `a`.`temp_reg_list_id` = `g`.`temp_reg_list_id`
                        )
                    )
                ) 
                join `temp_reg` `h` on(
                    (
                        `g`.`temp_reg_list_id` = `h`.`temp_reg_list_id`
                    )
                )
            ) 
            join `route_step` `i` on(
                (
                    `a`.`route_defn_id` = `i`.`route_id`
                )
            )
        ) 
        join `step_defn` `j` on(
            (
                `i`.`step_id` = `j`.`step_defn_id`
            )
        )
    )
```

This is how I find the route for a (the) *Transaction(s)*.

```
select *
from `Transaction` `A`
join `route_vw` `B`
on (
    (`B`.`facstaff` = `A`.`EmployeeClass`) 
    and (`B`.`waveposted` = `A`.`WavPost`) 
    and (`B`.`tempreg` = `A`.`Type`)
)
```

**Problem**

```
Array
(
    [EVENT_ID] => 4
    [Duration] => 0.003877
    [SQL_TEXT] => SELECT *
FROM Transaction A
INNER JOIN route_vw D on (
A.EmployeeClass = D.facstaff AND
A.WavPost = D.waveposted AND
A.Type = D.tempreg 
)
    [DIGEST_TEXT] => SELECT `d` . `facstaff` AS `facstaff` , `f` . `waveposted` AS `waveposted` , `h` . `tempreg` AS `tempreg` , `j` . `step_name` AS `step_name` , `i` . `route_step_id` AS `route_step_id` , `i` . `route_id` AS `route_id` , `i` . `step_id` AS `step_id` , `i` . `ndx` AS `ndx` , `i` . `on_time` AS `on_time` , `i` . `behind` AS `behind` , `i` . `late` AS `late` FROM ( ( ( ( ( ( ( ( `UchihaTigerTalent` . `route_defn` `a` JOIN `UchihaTigerTalent` . `fac_staff_list` `c` ON ( ( `a` . `fac_staff_list_id` = `c` . `fac_staff_list_id` ) ) ) JOIN `UchihaTigerTalent` . `fac_staff` `d` ON ( ( `c` . `fac_staff_list_id` = `d` . `fac_staff_list_id` ) ) ) JOIN `UchihaTigerTalent` . `wave_post_list` `e` ON ( ( `a` . `wave_post_list_id` = `e` . `wave_post_list_id` ) ) ) JOIN `UchihaTigerTalent` . `wave_post` `f` ON ( ( `e` . `wave_post_list_id` = `f` . `wave_post_list_id` ) ) ) JOIN `UchihaTigerTalent` . `temp_reg_list` `g` ON ( ( `a` . `temp_reg_list_id` = `g` . `temp_reg_list_id` ) ) ) JOIN 
    [NO_INDEX_USED] => 0
    [NO_GOOD_INDEX_USED] => 0
    [ROWS_AFFECTED] => 0
    [ROWS_SENT] => 214
    [ROWS_EXAMINED] => 820
)
```

These stats were taken when `Transaction` had 14 rows. Based on the `ROWS_EXAMINED` I don't think this method is going to scale up well. Is there a better way to write this so that I don't have to examine so many rows?

Note: I uploaded a [db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8ZNEW7YA5MnpEZnZgB74M8/5) demo.

**Update 1**

Question - "I don't understand your 1-column "*_list" tables."

Answer - The *_lists tables allows me to specify and reuse a set/list of values that a route should be used for.

E.G

[image]
[image]

Route #4 (`route_defn.route_defn_id = 4`) is applicable to Staff transactions.

Route #5 is applicable to Faculty transactions.

A route with fac_staff_list_id = 3 is applicable to both Faculty and Staff transactions.  * Note there are no routes with a fac_staff_list_id = 3.

This logic and structure applies to temp_reg_list and wave_post_list as well.

**Update 2**

"No intermediate table (*_list) is needed in a 1:many mapping. The fac_staff table simply needs a column route_defn_id. Get rid of the intervening fac_staff_list. (Ditto for other 1:many relationships.)" - @rick-james

"Please provide EXPLAIN SELECT ... and SHOW CREATE TABLE" - @rick-james

**The updated schema below is based on the suggestions from @rick-james.**

[image]

**show create view route_vw**

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=MERGE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW `route_vw` AS select `fac_staff`.`facstaff` AS `facstaff`,`wave_post`.`waveposted` AS `waveposted`,`temp_reg`.`tempreg` AS `tempreg`,`route_step`.`route_step_id` AS `route_step_id`,`route_step`.`route_id` AS `route_id`,`route_step`.`step_id` AS `step_id`,`route_step`.`ndx` AS `ndx`,`route_step`.`on_time` AS `on_time`,`route_step`.`behind` AS `behind`,`route_step`.`late` AS `late` from ((((`route_defn` join `fac_staff` on((`route_defn`.`route_defn_id` = `fac_staff`.`route_defn_id`))) join `wave_post` on((`route_defn`.`route_defn_id` = `wave_post`.`route_defn_id`))) join `temp_reg` on((`route_defn`.`route_defn_id` = `temp_reg`.`route_defn_id`))) join `route_step` on((`route_defn`.`route_defn_id` = `route_step`.`route_id`)))
```

**show create table route_defn**

```
CREATE TABLE `route_defn` (
 `route_defn_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 PRIMARY KEY (`route_defn_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

**show create table fac_staff**

```
CREATE TABLE `fac_staff` (
  `fs_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `route_defn_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `facstaff` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fs_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `route_defn_id` (`route_defn_id`,`facstaff`),
  KEY `facstaff` (`facstaff`),
  CONSTRAINT `fac_staff_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`route_defn_id`) REFERENCES `route_defn` (`route_defn_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=27 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

**show create table wave_post**

```
CREATE TABLE `wave_post` (
  `wp_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `route_defn_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `waveposted` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`wp_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `route_defn_id` (`route_defn_id`,`waveposted`),
  KEY `waveposted` (`waveposted`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=36 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

**show create table Transaction**

```
CREATE TABLE `Transaction` (
  `TID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Type` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `RequestType` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `WavPost` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `IncSupPosition` int(8) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `IncSupEmplid` int(6) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `Supervisor` varchar(55) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Location` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `HireMgrName` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `HireMgrEmail` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Comment` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `SalaryStart` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `PositionJustification` varchar(1500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `InternalComparison` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `AdditionalDuties` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ReducedTask` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PositionNumber` int(8) unsigned zerofill DEFAULT NULL,
  `StatePosition` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `JobReqID` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `JobCode` varchar(6) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `DepartmentID` int(4) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `DepartmentName` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `BudgetCenter` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `FullPart` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `StandardHours` float NOT NULL,
  `IncumbentEmplid` int(6) unsigned zerofill DEFAULT NULL,
  `IncumbentName` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PreHireEscalate` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''1'',
  `CountyCode` int(2) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `StateCode` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmployeeClass` char(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `SubmittedBy` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `TimeStamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `TID` (`TID`,`Type`,`WavPost`,`EmployeeClass`),
  KEY `BudgetCenter` (`BudgetCenter`),
  KEY `HireMgrEmail` (`HireMgrEmail`),
  KEY `SubmittedBy` (`SubmittedBy`),
  KEY `Type` (`Type`),
  KEY `EmployeeClass` (`EmployeeClass`),
  KEY `WavPost` (`WavPost`),
  KEY `Type_2` (`Type`,`WavPost`,`EmployeeClass`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6380 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

**show create table temp_reg**

```
CREATE TABLE `temp_reg` (
  `tr_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `route_defn_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tempreg` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tr_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `route_defn_id` (`route_defn_id`,`tempreg`),
  KEY `tempreg` (`tempreg`),
  KEY `rotue_defn_id` (`route_defn_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `temp_reg_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`route_defn_id`) REFERENCES `route_defn` (`route_defn_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=84 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

**show create table route_step**

```
CREATE TABLE `route_step` (
  `route_step_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `route_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `step_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ndx` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `on_time` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `behind` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `late` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`route_step_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `route_id_2` (`route_id`,`step_id`,`ndx`),
  KEY `step_id` (`step_id`),
  KEY `ndx` (`ndx`),
  KEY `route_id` (`route_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `route_step_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`step_id`) REFERENCES `step_defn` (`step_defn_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `route_step_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`route_id`) REFERENCES `route_defn` (`route_defn_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Room for **[discussing the question](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65292/optimizing-the-design-of-a-workflow-engine-database)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1 route is applicable many fac_staff types.

No intermediate table (*_list) is needed in a 1:many mapping.  The `fac_staff` table simply needs a column `route_defn_id`.  Get rid of the intervening `fac_staff_list`.  (Ditto for other 1:many relationships.)

Comment: After making your changes the query now does a Full Index Scan, a Full Table Scan, and the `NO_INDEX_USED` flag is true. Is this method going to scale worse than my method? Is there something I can do to fix the index and full scan issues?

Comment: The explain has `b`, but I don't see that in the query or in the view.  Please fix or clarify.  Instead of using `SELECT *`, specify _only_ the columns that you need.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for `fac_staff`, `fac_staff_list`, and `route_defn`.

Comment: Please see Update #2 once more. I added the `show create table` output and removed the view aliases.